# Java: How can I println an error message when the comand line argument is not a valid integer?

Tags: java

I made an application in Java that calculates the sum of all numbers up untill the input in the command line.

But, if one would put in a double or string in the command line i need to display an error message that says only real numbers can be put in.

How can i do this? I think it needs to be with exception or something?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 right here?
    int n    = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
       int n    = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      //here you print the error
       System.out.println("Error: only real numbers can be put in");
       //or
      System.err.println("Error: only real numbers can be put in");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to **`Integer.parseInt(args[0])`** does the hard work for you, it throws a **[`NumberFormatException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)** That you can simply catch and print any error message you like.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("The input value given is not a valid integer.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(args[0])` will throw a [NumberFormatException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if it cannot parse the string to an int. Simply catch it to handle the problem e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Bad user!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) or [numerous](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/index.html) [tutorials](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/understanding-java-exceptions) [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+exception) [spits](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html) out. This one straight from the official Java tutorials is usually a good bet: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Check out the information [here too](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-exception/java-parseint-exception.shtml). You can also see what exception `parseInt` raises, by looking up the API documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

I'm sure people are going to write the entire example up for you, in which case my answer is obsolete.

Try searching around, there's a ton of examples and tutorials on this kind of stuff online.